# Merge PDF files and preserve hyperlinks

Tags: pdf, preview

I have several PDF files that I want to merge. I used to do it with Preview in my macbook, where I open all the files and then use the Print -> Save as PDF.

However, this time, the files I want to merge have several Hyperlinks in the text and with this way, most of them get lost from the merged PDF file.

Is there any way to use Preview and keep the hyperlinks or is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Automator comes to the rescue. If you have time, you should really dive into it. You can do amazing stuff with it. I've a lot of custom actions and automations. Love this app. It's built into every Mac :D

Use this Automator Action: [Combine PDF](http://macosautomation.com/automator/combinePDFs)

1. [Download](http://macosautomation.com/automator/combinePDFs/CombinePDFService.zip) Automator Action (starts downloading)
2. Install automator action
3. Select PDF files you want to combine in Finder
4. Right click on selected files
5. Choose from Services the action Combine PDF files
6. Give the new file a name

Comment: This will not preserve hyperlinks functionality. Here is another way to do the same thing from CLI https://gotofritz.net/blog/howto/joining-pdf-files-in-os-x-from-the-command-line/